# How to have a aggregate function to select the first not null item from a column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

a example with real data:

```
CustomerId      Scope       Key                             Value
1               Customer    SelfPasswordReset_MaxAttempts   5
2               Customer    SelfPasswordReset_MaxAttempts   10
3               Customer    SelfPasswordReset_MaxAttempts   20
NULL            Platform    PlatformGUID                    c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
...
```

assume we further have a CustomerParant table

```
CustomerId  ParentId    Level
5           5           0
5           1           1
4           4           0
4           2           1
4           1           2
3           3           0
3           2           1
3           1           2
2           2           0
2           1           1
1           1           0
```

listing the parents of every customer and how much iterations you need to traverse through the tree to arrive there. means 3's parent is 2, 2's parent is 1 etc...

Now i want to build a query that returns a result like this:

```
CustomerId  SelfPasswordReset_MaxAttemps    PlatformGUID ... 
5           5                   c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
4           10                  c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
3           20                  c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
2           10                  c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
1           5                   c20414f6-3bd2-4d37-ac74-152b0efdb582
```

Special Note: Not every customer has his level defined. as you see i added customer 4 and 5 who don't have data a parameter defined of their own. they will inherit from their parent instead

Comment: In the new SQL Server 2022, as well as SQL Azure, you can do `FIRST_VALUE(...) IGNORE NULLS`, under older versions it's more complicated and requires multiple levels of nesting window functions, alternatively self-joined subqueries.

Comment: that is very good to know! you could even mark it as an answer if it works.
however for my particular scenario we can't use it since our customers demand we continue using comaptibility level 120 or so... but still it might be helpful for others! a related question: how do you sort a query before grouping? because it seems that order by group by is not supported... >.>

Comment: You can't as aggregate functions are not designed to have ordering in them. That's why I said you need to nest window functions. Even in 2022 you would need at least one

Comment: okay this is really bad... but thanks for clarifying

Comment: Can you share proper sample data, as well expected results? Your current example is unclear

Comment: i added a real world example with anonymized data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally SQL Coalesce function that returns a first defined which is non null value from argument list like

`Coalesce (NULL,1,2) // this will return 1`

`Coalesce (NULL,'abc','xyz') // this will return abc`

Comment: but sadly this is not an aggregate function as far as i know. :(
and it doesn't work if you have a dynamic range of values